# Mass modify product names for consistent formatting (for example, change XCode to Xcode)

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In my opinion, Ask Different would be great if Apple product names only appeared as:

- Xcode
- iPhone
- iPod touch
- iPad
- OS X
- Mac OS X

and I never saw:

- XCode, xCode, xcode, XCODE
- IPhone
- IPod Touch, iTouch
- IPad
- OSX
- Mac OSX, MacOS X

Are there ways to mass modify questions and answers here to enforce the formatting of Apple product names? I'd rather not search, manually edit, and implicitly bump old questions due to edits like this.

Comment: I completely agree, except for one thing. I never want to see "iPod Touch". (it's "iPod touch")

Comment: Related: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/444/automatically-capitalizing-ithing-and-ithing-to-ithing

Comment: @KyleCronin Ah, you're right; edited.

Comment: Also, "iTouch" makes me shudder.

Comment: Personal preferences (and "iTouch") aside, I'm having a hard time seeing how this makes things better in a tangible way.

Comment: See also http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/q/45/11791

Comment: @jaberg consistency. If you use the proper terms®, it looks like you know what you are talking about.

Comment: It's much easier to read material if it follows a consistent style.  Even more if you are distracted by misbehaving hardware or software.